# Starting over on a new laptop

Tags: system-installation

My old laptop crash and was not able to retrieve anything from hard drive. I want to install Ubuntu on my new laptop. What would be the best way of going about this? Last time I had to download everything on a disk and then install Ubuntu. Do I need to do that again? Would a stick work as well as a disk? I liked what I could do before and I want to get off of Windows.

Comment: If your laptop is a UEFI machine, go with a 64 bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Either way you need to download the ISO from [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) you can either download the 32bit, or 64bit, depending on your machine.  Once downloaded, you can either create a bootable CD/DVD, or a USB bootable stick.  For more information on hoe=w to create either the CD/DVD, or the USB stick you can visit [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I have understood correctly.If you want to install ubuntu on your new laptop,you will need a usb drive or a cd.Download Linux live Usb creater from [here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download).Oncve installed follow the steps.

Step 1: Select your usb key.

Step 2:Choose "Download".(It will ask to select a folder)

Step 3:Leave this step as it is.

Step 4:Tick on first and second box.(Remember to back up your key before proceeding to next step.)

Step 5:Click on the lighting icon and wait for it to finish. Your key is now ready.
Restart your pc and select "Boot from usb(name of your key)" from boot menu.Ubuntu will run in live mode.Click on "install" icon on Desktop.Follow the instructions and you are done.